# In: for i in temp/*; do when I use i it contains the path temp/ and I do not want this?

Tags: bash

I have the magick absolute in a folder and in a sub-folder temp I have images. I need/want to process the images and write them to another sub-folder output.

```
folder (with magick)
    temp sub-folder (with input files)
    output sub-folder (where processed images are placed)
```

But I am unable to stop the variable i picking up the path temp/. How do I stop it? Do I have to strip the characters temp/ from i then use it? Or is there a simple way to do this?

```
for i in temp/*; do
    ./magick convert -resize 450 -strip -quality 90% temp/$i output/$i
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with parameter expansion:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for i in temp/*; do
    ./magick convert -resize 450 -strip -quality 90% "$i" "output/${i#temp/}"
done
```

The `nullglob` prevents 0 matches from expanding to the pattern.

Maybe you can also just change working directory to `temp` and use `..`.  I'm just not sure if `magick` will still work if referred from a different directory.

```
cd temp || exit

for i in *; do
    ../magick convert -resize 450 -strip -quality 90% "$i" "../output/$i"
done
```